# Java - Access to correct line in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a scanner that scans source files and outputs me the data (including line numbers). After that I add some information in commentary the above line

For example:

```
Line line;
Code code = new Code("This should be commented");
```

And after

```
Line line;
//Comment
Code code = new Code("This should be commented");
```

But I comment multiple lines in each file. So, the line numbers is changing. How can I access to the correct line? Before editing a file, I have a set of lines I should comment. I through I should check each file and increment the line number if a comment was added on a line before in this file, but is that the best way?

Comment: Why not just skip the lines that start with `//` when you are reading your file?

Comment: Because the commentary contains information about a found vulnerability, it might be marked as fixed and I should confirm it, so I cannot skip anything

Comment: Well, if your program keeps adding new lines; I guess your program should appropriately increase that line number counter.

Comment: Index all the lines first and then just update all indexes when the line count changes.

Comment: I did something like this. I created ArrayList with an object that keeps file contents by lines. To add a comment, I do something like this: `lines.set(n, comment + "\n" + lines.get(n));` and when adding a new comment, I check each time if the file is not exist, but if it is, I just update the line. But this algorithm looks like for me a code monkey

Comment: Big problem I'm seeing here is apparently you add comments as part of processing the source file without anyway to mark the comment as having been generated by this process.  In otherwords, how could anyone or anything tell where a comment came from and thus if it's line number should be counted?

Comment: If the comment is already exist, it won't be added one more time (I has specific format and the scanner's name inside itself)

Comment: What I mean is whoever wrote the code you're scanning was free to write any comment they darn well pleased.  What they added might look the same as whatever you were going to add.  You need some escape mechanism so you can reliably identify your generated comments.  Do that and the process is reversible.  You can automate striping out the added comments and regenerate any lines original line number

Comment: But I don't believe that someone will add something like this by herself: `//<marker>: Scanner <short vulnerability type> Issue #<num>, <long vulnerability type>, <severity>, <URL>`. Even if she adds this, but vulnerability doesn't exist, marker will be changed to FIXED and all.